# how do you return a property and save it as a global variable? (python)

Tags: python, properties

here is my code:

```
def createProp(fget, fset, fdel):

    class prop(object):
        get=property(fget,fset,fdel)

    return prop().get
x=createProp(getter,setter,deleter)
```

what I would like to do is have it return a property, so that I can make the variable x a property, but I can't figure out how to make a function like this. what it is doing instead is returning the value of the property, not the property itself.

python 2.6

Comment: You are creating a property of the prop object, then calling it.  I'm not sure how a property object outside of a class would make sense though; a property is basically an encapsulated set of accessors to a pseudo-private or calculated piece of data in a class instance.  Could you explain your use case for this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
createProp = property
```

Properties are perfectly ordinary objects. `property` is just another class. You can create an instance of it at runtime, in whatever context you want (no need for a class), pass them around, etc. And yes, you could (pointlessly) create one in a local class and then fetch it from there. But as the whole point of properties is overriding attribute access on instance, you'd have to fetch it from the class: `return prop.get`.

However, as `property` works its magic by means of the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), and descriptors have to be in a class to work. You can't have a global (or local) variable that's a property -- well, you can, but using it would just give you the descriptor object, not run `fget`, and assignment wouldn't trigger `fset`. You cannot do anything like that, and you shouldn't.

Comment: so if I can't make a global property, is there some other workaround for making a function that returns a constant?

Comment: @QxQ "a function that returns a constant" is an entirely different thing and as simple as `def f(): return <constant>`. Please clarify.

Comment: I was thinking that properties let you create a setter that throws an error if you try to change it, but I can't use them as a global variable, so I would like to know some other workaround to restrict the access of a variable (and simular things like that).

Comment: If you want a real constant (a global that cannot change): I doubt it's possible without hijacking `sys.modules` and replacing the module object of your module. And I'm not sure if that would affect code within the module (perhaps you'd have to mess with all the function objects). In short, it's not viable. It breaks some advanced, but justified use cases (e.g. patching for unit-tests), actual bugs caused by this are rare (a proper naming convention helps: pep8 demands `CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS`), and it obscurity and difficulties ruins any other advantage it may have. Just accept Python's rules.